# Swift switch not working with C++ based enum

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums, switch-statement

I'm trying to learn Swift by converting an existing Objective-C app I wrote (a streaming audio player). However, the libraries I'm using don't have Swift equivalents, so I've created a bridging header and am referencing them successfully.

Now, I'm trying to do a switch on an `enum` from one of these libraries, but Swift is just complaining.

To make things even more confusing (for me, probably not for any of you), a series of `if` blocks works fine.

Here is the enum from the Objective-C library:

```
typedef enum {
    kFsAudioStreamRetrievingURL,
    kFsAudioStreamStopped,
    kFsAudioStreamBuffering,
    kFsAudioStreamPlaying,
    kFsAudioStreamPaused,
    kFsAudioStreamSeeking,
    kFSAudioStreamEndOfFile,
    kFsAudioStreamFailed,
    kFsAudioStreamRetryingStarted,
    kFsAudioStreamRetryingSucceeded,
    kFsAudioStreamRetryingFailed,
    kFsAudioStreamPlaybackCompleted,
    kFsAudioStreamUnknownState
} FSAudioStreamState;
```

This works:

```
if (state == kFsAudioStreamRetrievingURL) {
}
if (state == kFsAudioStreamStopped) {
}
if (state == kFsAudioStreamBuffering) {
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
switch state {
    case kFsAudioStreamRetrievingURL:
    case kFsAudioStreamStopped:
    case kFsAudioStreamBuffering:
    break;
}
```

The second one gives me the following error:

```
Binary operator '~=' cannot be applied to two 'FSAudioStreamState' operands
```

I would appreciate any assistance in helping me learn more Swift!

Comment: Pls see my answer, I think it's not obj-c enumeration  (it's c/c++ enumeration).

Comment: Hi, did you converted this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
switch state {
     case .RetrievingURL:
     case .Stopped:
     case .Buffering:
     ...
}
```

**---- EDITED!!! ----**

I'm wrong, this is C++ enum. So try this:

```
switch state.value {
    case kFsAudioStreamRetrievingURL.value:
    case kFsAudioStreamStopped.value:
    case kFsAudioStreamBuffering.value:
    ...
```

}

Comment: Sadly, that just returns this:
`Enum case 'RetrievingURL' not found in type 'FSAudioStreamState'`

Comment: I had to make a tiny change (`.value` -> `.rawValue`) but it works great now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In obj-c
Enum definition should be

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, FSAudioStreamState){
      FSAudioStreamStateStopped,
      ...
}
```

So when they are imported into Swift

```
enum FSAudioStreamState{
     case Stopped
     ...
}
```

I think it's C++ enum (Not Objective-C enum), so swift will not regard it as enum and it would be better to use if - else.

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't involve modifying the underlying library (because that's externally managed). But I shall do some searching on C++ enums to see if I can find anything there.

Comment: It's just C++ enum so you can't use swift's interoperability.